# how to prevent the change of input type password to text in debugger mode

Tags: html

In any web page,We can see the password in this manner:

1. Inspect the element using firebug.
2. Go to textbox (where anyone can type the password) in firebug.
3. Change the type of input box from password to text.
4. Now you can see the password.

How to prevent this?

Comment: You can't - that's the whole point of debugging.

Comment: And how this is a problem?

Comment: So..... I can see the password which I just typed into the box... Oh noes!!

Comment: You can't and why would you anyway? It's only a security issue if someone type in their password, don't submit the form and let somebody access their system during that time.

Comment: In the extrem case you could build your own input password using javascript, but like my collegues said, this is not a security issue.

Comment: Also even if doing it via JS and leaving nothing on the HTML from the debugger one could probably extract the value still. Wrap the form in Flash :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no concern of safety there. As it won't save it on the server, and it will only be for him that he can see the password. It should be alright to see you're own password right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. If you are concerned about someone seeing the password later by doing this first off note that your users should be smart enough and almost every application uses this. If you are really paranoid you could log the keystrokes showing no password or create your own display of some sort, which would make it a little harder to view such information but any knowledgible attacker could find out the password with full access.